# Tournament management application - how to manage players and teams?

Tags: c#, .net, database, database-design, data-modeling

I'm writing an archery tournament management application. This application will be run on judge's laptop with no internet connection.

It is made to easily manage players, teams and their scores and points.
I'm writing in C# .NET.

**My problem:**

There will be around 100 players that are grouped into about 20 teams.
What is the best way of storing information about players and teams?
How to save that information to disc?  I can't install any other software on judge's PC (so no local MySQL).

Can you give me some ideas?

Maybe in future there will be more then one people entering scores at once (possible LAN connection). How to adapt to this? (This is less important, for now I need 1 pc functionality).

Comment: Can you install SQL Server on the judge's PC?

Comment: @Greg I said. Only my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is probably way to go.  It's an imbedded DB that does not have to be installed separately (In other words, you can install it with your program.)

Answer (score 2):

If you create a DataSet with DataTables you can save the tables to XML. If you keep the domain separated from your other code you can easily replace the dataset with a database, see Repository Pattern.

Comment: One offtopic queation. How to change order of databes columns in databes designer?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. The order of columns shouldn't matter.